# How to retrieve a user's tweets without retweets and replies in R?

Tags: r, twitter, nlp, twitter-oauth

I want to retrieve a user's tweets for text analytics purposes. I already tried *userTimeline* from *twitteR package*, but it only retrieves 3200 tweets including replies and retweets. Is there other options available to download only tweets of a user using R?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It is a site for programming and code questions, rather than recommending software or packages. Having said that have you had a look at the relevant cran task view for text analysis: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/?

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for recommendation. I checked for "Twitter", "text analysis", but did not find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I've never coded in R before, but I have some experience with the Twitter API and have done something similar in Tweepy library using python.

The status object has several attributes which you can read about [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object);

You can check if a tweet is a retweet by checking if the tweet object has ***retweeted_status*** attribute.

You can check if the tweet is a reply to another tweet by checking the ***in_reply_to_status_id*** attribute. This attribute returns the ID of the tweet being replied to if the tweet is a reply and None if it's not.

In python, the code for implementing this would be;

```
get_tweets = api.user_timeline(username)
for tweets in get_tweets:
    if hasattr(tweets, 'retweeted_status') or tweets.in_reply_to_status_id != None:
        #Do stuff if the tweet is a retweet or reply
    else:
        #Do some other stuff if the tweet is not a retweet or reply
```

Try to convert that to the R equivalent.